# Getting the result of a then within a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to deal with the following issue.

In the code below I am trying to get the result from the inner `then` function. I would expect that the `let online` function will return `onlineResult.stream`. However, it returns:

[image]

If would expect:
[image]

or `null` when it is empty.

```js
var baseUrl = "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api";
var channels = [
  "ESL_SC2",
  "OgamingSC2",
  "cretetion",
  "freecodecamp",
  "storbeck",
  "habathcx",
  "RobotCaleb",
  "noobs2ninjas"
];

function fetchChannels(channels) {

  var listItems = [];
  if (Array.isArray(channels)) {

    const results = channels.map(channel =>
      $.getJSON(`${baseUrl}/channels/${channel}?callback=?`)
    );

    Promise.all(results).then(values => {
      values.forEach(val => {

        let online = $.getJSON(`${baseUrl}/streams/${val.name}?callback=?`)
          .then(onlineResult => {
            return onlineResult.stream;
          })
        console.log(online);
        listItems.push([val.name, val.logo]);
      });
    });
  }
}

fetchChannels(channels);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `then` returns *a promise for* the result of the callback. It cannot return the result of the callback that hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: @Bergi ok I understand. So how could I get the result of the `$.getJSON(`${baseUrl}/streams/${val.name}?callback=?`)`. In other words how should I structure my code?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `online` value? If all you wanted was to log it, just put the `console.log` statement inside the `then` callback.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is add a `then()` to the first channel request and get the stream associated with that channel as soon as it arrives

Something like:

```js
var baseUrl = "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api";
var channels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2"];

function fetchChannels(channels) {

  if (!Array.isArray(channels)) {
    return Promise.reject('No channels array')
  } else {
    const channelPromises = channels.map(channel =>
      $.getJSON(`${baseUrl}/channels/${channel}?callback=?`)
      .then(fetchStream)
    );

    return Promise.all(channelPromises)
  }

  function fetchStream(channelResult) {

    return $.getJSON(`${baseUrl}/streams/${channelResult.name}?callback=?`)
      .then(streamResult => {
        return streamResult.stream;
      }).then(stream => {
        // adding the result of stream request as property of channel request ... adapt as needed
        channelResult.stream = stream;
        return channelResult
      })
  }
}

fetchChannels(channels)
  .then(res => console.log(res))// array of channel requests, each has a `"stream"` property
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Assuming `streamResult.stream` is not a promise, you probably would not chain `then` calls but use only a single callback